# Upgrading apache cxf to 3.4.1 resulting in error

Tags: java, cxf, soap-client

Upgrading cxf version from 3.2.1 to 3.4.1 resulting in below when SOAP service is accessed.

javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException:Response message did not contain proper response data.
org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl$IllegalEmptyResponseException: Response message did not contain proper response data.

Comment: Can you please increase the log level (e.g. turn on request/ response logging) and provide more details for analysis?

Comment: @DennisKieselhorst, i had raised jira with Apache cxf team - https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CXF-8452, seems to be an expected behaviour.